# SQL matching columns between rows

Tags: sql, select

I need to write a select statement which gathers not only information from multiple tables, but information from within a certain table which matches data in other rows within that same table.

So while joins would work for the multiple table issue, as far as I am aware I cannot "join" column a and column b in the same table.

Here's the detail

I have the following tables

CR, VM and Folder

I need to select the following:

ID and Name from CR

Folder Name

Folder name however is not in the folder table, to find it, I need to first take "ID" from CR and match it to "ObjectID" in VM - then the column "Location" in that row matches the ObjectID of another row in the VM table.

I need to then match ID in folder to that ObjectID and retrieve "Name" in the table "Folder" to retrieve the folder name".

I don't quite know where to start, should I use cursors for this?

Comment: You actually _can_ join across columns in the same table. A JOIN can have an arbitrary expression in its `ON` clause. Please post some sample data from your tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to join a table against itself by aliasing one side of the join.  This may be enough to get you started. Otherwise we would need to see some sample data.

```
SELECT
  CR.ID,
  CR.Name,
  Folder.Name AS FolderName
FROM
  CR
  /* First join CR to VM */
  INNER JOIN VM ON CR.ID = VM.ObjectID
  /* Then join VM to itself aliased as VMLoc, mapping Location to ObjectID */
  INNER JOIN VM AS VMLoc ON VM.Location = VMLoc.ObjectID
  /* Finally join the second ObjectID to Folder to get Folder.Name */
  INNER JOIN Folder ON Folder.ID = VMLoc.ObjectID
```

Comment: Perfect. Once I knew I could alias a table and join it to itself, everything else fell into place. The script is now finished and works. Many thanks.